# How to collect elements in one list with the constraints provided in a second list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I wish to collect the items in the first list provided the constraints in the second list. For example in the lists shown below the first list shows a bunch of strings and the second list shows the positions of the strings as they appear in a string:

```
{StringCases[#1, RegularExpression[#2]],
StringPosition[#1,RegularExpression[#2]]} &["tthis is a book fine", "(?:is|book|t)"]

{{"t", "t", "is", "is", "book"}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 5}, {7, 8}, {12, 15}}}
```

The output I am desperately trying to get should look like as follow:

```
{"tt","is","is","book"}
```

The rational behind the result is that since the first two elements are `"t"` and differ only by one unit which is the distance between them so they occur consecutively i.e. `1+1 = 2`.

On the other hand however, the first instance of `"is"` occupies position 4-5 in the string and the second occurence of `"is"` is situated at positions 7-8, and is separated by a space (they do not occur consecutively as `4+2 = 6` and not 7). Therefore `"is"` do not merge.

I am struggling to find a way and would very much appreciate if someone can kindly help me with the problem. Thanks in advance !

Comment: So what is the input, lists or the string? In case of the string, is this what you are after? `StringCases["tthis is a book fine", Repeated /@ {"is", "book", "t"}]`

Comment: Many thanks !!! Your solution made the second list redundant. I have followed some of your other codes and am fascinated by your knowledge of Mathematica. If you do not mind, may I ask you for your contact details, as in an email. Thanks again !

Comment: Thanks :) Let's use SE platform to communicate first :) If you fail to find an answer to your questions you can ask new one, or ask on chat. I'm not the only one who can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, we can get the result directly.

```
StringCases["tthis is a book fine", Repeated /@ {"is", "book", "t"}]
```

> ```
> {"tt","is","is","book"}
> ```